# Where can I find capital outflow data?

Tags: macroeconomics, capital, data

I'm studying capital outflow and I need to compare its growth from 1990 to 2014 in different countries.

I can't find the data, please help

Comment: Please indicate the efforts you have taken before we respond, thank you.

Comment: Ob Bloomberg you could for example use {FFLO<GO>} Fund flows by country as well as {WFII<GO>} Foreign portfolio investment.

Answer (score 2):

I found the data I needed on the IMF website